# Learning OpenGL with a Strong Math Foundation?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I am looking to learn open GL, I have a strong foundation of the maths behind graphics. What is the best route to take in learning the Open GL technology i'm open to using both Windows and Mac.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. http://www.opengl.org/
2. [OpenGL programming guide aka "Red Book"](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/)
3. Francis s Hill, "Computer Graphics using OpenGL".
4. [OpenGL shading language (aka "Orange Book")](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334892)
5. [NVidia OpenGL resources](http://developer.nvidia.com/page/opengl.html).
6. And you might want to take a look at [OpenGL reference manucal ("Blue Book")](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/blue_book/)

Answer (score 2):

The [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) are good, though they assume you have some experience with C/C++. If you don't have that coding experience, you'll want to brush up on that at the same time (sorry, I don't have a link to a favourite C/C++ tutorial).

As far as books go, I used to like the [OpenGL Superbible](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/), and it looks like there's a new edition on its way! :)

Comment: Sorry I should of made it clear that I can code C and C++ well, using it in my job but you say that the OpenGl Superbible is good?

Comment: OpenGL Superbible was good when I last looked at it about 6 years ago. If there's a new version coming soon, I'd wait for it, and start with the NeHe tutorials. I don't know if they've been kept up to date, but they should still be good at introducing the basic concepts.